# Importing Setuptools tools error (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools') Python

Tags: python, import, error-handling, pip, setuptools

I get an error when I try to import setuptools, I have python version Python 3.9.12 and I have the following packages and versions below. I am on a windows 10 system. Anyone know how to fix this?

Error:

```
    from setuptools import setup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

Packages and versions

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
Cython     0.29.30
pip        22.1
setuptools 58.1.0
```

Comment: What command did you run to ger the packages and versions?

Comment: I used `pip list`